# Disable Copilot trial

Tags: visual-studio, github-copilot

I can't get rid of Github Copilot trial prompts in Visual Studio 2022 Pro.

I don't want Github Copilot. I never wanted Github Copilot. Yet I keep getting prompts and warnings in Visual Studio 2022 Pro about it.

I can't remove the extension because it's a trial. I will never subscribe to it, so I don't even want the trial.

How can I get rid of the VS prompts and remove the trial from Github?